# How to send Snowflake Cloud Data Platform query results using email?

Tags: email, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to send an email from Snowflake Cloud Data Platform and attach the results of a query.

How can I do that?

Comment: Not directly as a functionality but using external functions. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989803/sending-email-alerts-from-snowflake)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending Email alerts from Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989803/sending-email-alerts-from-snowflake)

Comment: And if you don't want to use a Lambda function, you could also simply use an SNS API call from a Snowflake External function, and the subscribe to the topic with the email that you want to send the information to.  That'll skip the Lambda piece.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake can send emails now with `call system$send_email()`. You can call this to send the results of your query.

Read more:

- https://hoffa.medium.com/hey-snowflake-send-me-an-email-243741a0fe3

The basic block that allows you to send emails:

```sql
call system$send_email(
    'my_email_int',
    'felipe@example.com, dan@example.com, rajiv@example.com',
    'This is the subject',
    'This is the body'
);
```

Comment: That sounds great, does it email the results in the body of the email or as an attachment?