# How to send an email when a task has failed?

Tags: email, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a task in Snowflake that gets executed by calling a stored procedure. I want to get an email notification whenever a task fails. Is this possible with Snowflake? I have seen a "notification integration" object, but I am not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Natively there are no such utilities for sending notifications for task run results. What you can do is build notification mechanism as detailed here : [Sending Email alerts from Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989803/sending-email-alerts-from-snowflake)

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake can send emails now with `call system$send_email()`.

For example:

```sql
call system$send_email(
    'my_email_int',
    'felipe@example.com, dan@example.com, rajiv@example.com',
    'This is the subject',
    'This is the body'
);
```

Read more:

- https://hoffa.medium.com/hey-snowflake-send-me-an-email-243741a0fe3

Answer (score 0):

Calling `system$send_email` has one pretty severe restriction:  you can only send emails to verified email addresses belonging to users defined in your account.  Snowflake documentation: [https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/email-stored-procedures#:~:text=Email%20notifications%20can%20only%20be%20sent%20to%20Snowflake%20users%20within%20the%20same%20account%2C%20and%20those%20users%20must%20verify%20their%20email%20addresses](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/email-stored-procedures#:%7E:text=Email%20notifications%20can%20only%20be%20sent%20to%20Snowflake%20users%20within%20the%20same%20account%2C%20and%20those%20users%20must%20verify%20their%20email%20addresses)

You can send emails to external addresses using a Lambda.  This article describes one technique that can send to exteral addresses and send an attachment with data from a table: [How to send an email when a task has failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944516)